# How to change return value of jasmine spy?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, spy

I'm using Jasmine to create a spy like so:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    $state = $injector.get('$state');
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

    socket = new sockMock($rootScope);

    //this is the line of interest
    authService = jasmine.createSpyObj('authService', ['login', 'logout', 'currentUser']);
}));
```

I'd like to be able to change what's returned by the various methods of `authService`.

Here are how the actual tests are set up:

```
function createController() {
    return $controller('UserMatchingController', {'$scope': $rootScope, 'socket':socket, 'authService': authService });
}

describe('on initialization', function(){
    it('socket should emit a match', function() {
        createController();

        expect(socket.emits['match'].length).toBe(1);
    });

    it('should transition to users.matched upon receiving matched', function(){

        //this line fails with "TypeError: undefined is not a function"
        authService.currentUser.andReturn('bob');

        createController();

        $state.expectTransitionTo('users.matched');
        socket.receive('matchedblah', {name: 'name'});

        expect(authService.currentUser).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
})
```

Here's how the controller is set up:

```
lunchrControllers.controller('UserMatchingController', ['$state', 'socket', 'authService',
    function ($state, socket, authService) {
        socket.emit('match', {user: authService.currentUser()});

        socket.on('matched' + authService.currentUser(), function (data) {
            $state.go('users.matched', {name: data.name})
        });
    }]);
```

Essentially, I'd like to be able to change the return value of spied methods. However, I'm not sure if I'm correctly approaching the problem by using `jasmine.createSpyObj`.

Comment: What version of Jasmine?

Comment: I have ```"jasmine-core": "~2.2.0"``` in ```package.json```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try this instead.  The API changed for Jasmine 2.0:

```
authService.currentUser.and.returnValue('bob');
```

Documentation:

https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/spying_on_properties

Answer (score 1):

We can overwrite it like,

`updateService.getUpdate = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue('bob')`